# Como reunir dados de duas consultas em um objeto php?

Tags: php, pdo

Estou fazendo duas consultas no BD em tabelas diferentes.
Com os dados da primeira consulta estou pegando dados na outra, porém, não consigo juntar todos os dados em um objeto json só.

```
<?php
include_once("con.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$pegaContaAdmin=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM contaPadrao");
$pegaContaAdmin->execute();

$return = array();

while ($linhaContaAdmin=$pegaContaAdmin->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $idcontaPadrao = $linhaContaAdmin['idcontaPadrao'];
        $contaPadrao = $linhaContaAdmin['contaPadrao'];
        $idsubcategoriaPadrao = $linhaContaAdmin['subcategoriaPadrao_idsubcategoriaPadrao'];

        $return[] = array(
                'idcontaPadrao' => $idcontaPadrao,
                'contaPadrao'   => $contaPadrao,
            );

    $pegaDadosSubcategoria=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM subcategoriaPadrao 
                                          WHERE idsubcategoriaPadrao=:idsubcategoriaPadrao");
    $pegaDadosSubcategoria->bindValue("idsubcategoriaPadrao", $idsubcategoriaPadrao);
    $pegaDadosSubcategoria->execute();


    while ($linhaDadosSubcate=$pegaDadosSubcategoria->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $subcategoriaPadrao = utf8_encode($linhaDadosSubcate['subcategoriaPadrao']);
            $tipo = $linhaDadosSubcate['tipo'];

        }
}

$return['subcategoriaPadrao'] = $subcategoriaPadrao;
$return['tipo'] = $tipo;

echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Comment: Qual é o resultado que está obtendo e qual deveria ser? A princípio, a linha aonde insere `idcontaPadrao` e `contaPadrao` vai inserir em um índice pré-existente (0), mas não haverá conflito pois lá já existe um array.

Comment: Atualizei o post e coloquei o resultados que está aparecendo.
Porém, deveria vir 2 resultados e não só 1.

Comment: Não vejo "erros" no seu código, talvez equívocos. Por exemplo, a consulta `$pegaContaAdmin` só vai trazer o último resultado, visto que está em um `while` e sempre preencherá as mesmas variáveis. Já na consulta `$pegaDadosSubcategoria`, está buscando por `idsubcategoriaPadrao`, e ao que parece, só possui um registro.

Comment: Como sugere que eu faça pra trazer todos os registro do $pegaContaAdmin?
Eu teria que colocar todo os resto do código, dentro do 1o. while, certo?

Answer (score 1):

Conforme as mensagens nos comentários, o problema pode ser pelo uso do `while` não ser encadeado. Para facilitar algumas coisas, eu também mudaria um pouco a estrutura.

Em primeiro lugar, traria somente os dados necessários:

```
$pegaContaAdmin = $pdo->prepare("SELECT idcontaPadrao , contaPadrao , subcategoriaPadrao_idsubcategoriaPadrao FROM contaPadrao");
```

Como a ideia é retornar todos os dados, já utilizaria a própria PDO pra isso:

```
$return = $pegaContaAdmin->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//nunca se esqueça de fechar o cursor, pode gerar problemas.
$pegaContaAdmin->closeCursor();
```

Para os dados da subcategoria, ao invés de um `while`, eu usaria um `foreach`, inserindo os dados no array já existente:

```
//o prepare pode ser deixado do lado de fora do foreach, apenas a variável que conterá o bind mudará.
$pegaDadosSubcategoria = $pdo->prepare("SELECT subcategoriaPadrao , tipo FROM subcategoriaPadrao WHERE idsubcategoriaPadrao=:idsubcategoriaPadrao");

//sendo $row passada como referência para poder alterar o valor do array $return
foreach($return as &$row)
{
    $pegaDadosSubcategoria->bindValue("idsubcategoriaPadrao", $row['idsubcategoriaPadrao');
    $pegaDadosSubcategoria->execute();

    while ($linhaDadosSubcate = $pegaDadosSubcategoria->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        //realiza o encode que já existe em seu código
        $linhaDadosSubcate['subcategoriaPadrao'] =  utf8_encode($linhaDadosSubcate['subcategoriaPadrao']);

        //cria uma lista de subcategorias dentro de cada registro da categoria padrão
        $row['subcategoria'][] = $linhaDadosSubcate;
    }
}

//nunca se esqueça de fechar o cursor, pode gerar problemas.
$pegaDadosSubcategoria->closeCursor();
```

Após, é só imprimir

```
echo json_encode($return);
```

Conforme conversamos, acredito que isso resolva os seus problemas.

Comment: Vou tentar Gabriel

Comment: Gabriel, rodei seus códigos e apareceu a seguinte mensagem no console:
angular.js:11881GET http://localhost:8888/sistemas/webApps/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_2.0/php/pegaContaAdmin.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: O erro postado não me diz muita coisa. Lembrando que os códigos são apenas exemplos. Vai precisar verificar o log do php ou apache para verificar o erro.

Comment: Achei que seu código estivesse pronto kkkk que era só copiar e colocar kkkk

Comment: @GustavoSevero Em boa parte sim, mas como só foi postada uma parte do seu código, só consegui realizar sobre o que você passou.

Comment: Mas o que postei foi todo o meu código php, não falta nada.

Comment: De qualquer forma, eu apenas indiquei pequenos pontos de alteração.

Comment: Gabriel, você pode fazer as alterações com base no meu código?

Comment: Não, não posso. O intuito é auxiliar e ensinar. Faça como você conseguir, traga os códigos e/ou os erros. Assim, então, lhe auxiliaremos com os erros. Além do mais, o código de exemplo já é 100% do seu código, apenas partes dele.

Comment: Pois, mas infelizmente, não em ajudou.